# Почему перестал работать margin-left?

Tags: html, css

На протяжении всего кода, данное свойство работало. Но в классе marketing оно перестало работать. Почему? (ссылка на rectangle2 - это всегда самая длинная линия)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.design {
  text-align: center;
  color: #1d1d1d;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 12px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-right: 435px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.procent {
  text-align: center;
  color: #1d1d1d;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 12px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-right: 280px;
  margin-top: -26px;
}

.rectangle2 {
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-left: 77px;
}

.rectangle1 {
  margin-top: -18px;
  margin-left: 77px;
}

.development {
  text-align: center;
  color: #1d1d1d;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 12px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-right: 390px;
  margin-top: 33px;
}

.procent1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #1d1d1d;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 12px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-right: 192px;
  margin-top: -27px;
}

.rectangle4 {
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-left: 77px;
}

.rectangle3 {
  margin-top: -18px;
  margin-left: 77px;
}

.marketing {
  text-align: center;
  color: #1d1d1d;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 12px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-right: 450px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.procent2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #1d1d1d;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 12px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-right: 300px;
  margin-top: -27px;
}

.rectange7 {
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-left: 77px;
}

.rectangle5 {
  margin-top: -18px;
  margin-left: 77px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!--Professional Skills-->
  <div class="skills">
    <div class="smth">
      <h3 class="titelpr">Professional Skills</h3>
      <!--UI/UX Design-->
      <p class="design">UI/UX DESIGN</p>
      <p class="procent">75%</p>
      <!--Rectangles for UI/UX Design-->
      <div class="rectangle2">
        <img src="rectangle2.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="rectangle1">
        <img src="rectangle1.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <!--Web-delepoment-->
      <p class="development">WEB DEVELOPMENT </p>
      <p class="procent1">90%</p>
      <!--Rectangles for Web development-->
      <div class="rectangle4">
        <img src="rectangle2.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="rectangle3">
        <img src="rectangle3.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <!--marketing-->
      <p class="marketing">MARKETING</p>
      <p class="procent2">65%</p>
      <!--Rectangles for marketing-->
      <div class="rectangle7">
        <img src="rectangle2.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="rectangle5">
        <img src="rectangle5.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

предполагаю, потому что

```
.**rectange7** {
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-left: 77px;
}
```

не содержит буквы **l**

))) (rectang**L**e != rectange)
НО! это не банальная опечатка, вы осознано создали условия для своей ошибки, используя неинформативные названия для классов. Рекомендую Вам почитать про именование классов в css (а-ля БЭМ методология).